# Unconfigured DbContext in .NET Core console app

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, dbcontext

I have developed a .NET 6 console application using EF Core with 3 layered projects (Presentation, BLL, DAL).

I would like to use the generic connection string provided in my `appsettings.json` for the `DbContext`.

This is what I have declared in my `Program.cs` of my presentation layer:

```
static void Main()
{
    var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

    _configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();            

    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString")));
    // ....
}
```

The `_configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString")` is returning the correct connection string.

However when I use my `MyContext`, it keeps returning the following message:

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext

The only solution I have found would be to override my `MyContext` in the DAL project by doing

```
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{      
     public MyContext()
     { }

     public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
            : base(options)
     {
     }

     public virtual DbSet<....> .... { get; set; }

     protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
         modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new Configurations....Configuration());

         OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
     }

     protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
     {     
         optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=DB;Initial Catalog=Base;Trusted_Connection=True;");
     }

     partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}
```

However, this is not what I want as I have to repeat the connection string again in the solution. I want the connection string to come from the `appsettings.json` (as it can depend of the environment (dev, prod))). Is there a way to do so?

Moreover, why the `AddDbContext` in the `Program.cs` doesn't work? It works fine for all my ASP.NET Core 6 web apps. Is it different for console applications?

Comment: In `OnConfiguring` use condition `if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured) optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer`

Comment: And how are you instantiating your db context? I guess you understand that `AddDbContext` works only with DI. `public MyContext() { }` constructor looks suspicious as it allows using `new MyContext()` in which case of course the context won't be configured. Remove that constructor (as well as `OnConfiguring` override) and make sure to obtain db context only from DI container.